# How to convert a coordinates to indice array (vice versa) in a NetworkX graph?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, dijkstra, networkx, astar

I want to use a raster for a A* and bidirectional Dijkstra path analysis in NetworkX. I am using Python for this project.

Raster example (it's a png file converted when uploaded, but the real problem is TIFF):
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Kip.png)

First I read in the raster with GDAL

```
input_raster = "raster.tif"
raster = gdal.Open(input_raster)
```

Next I read the raster as an array

```
bandraster = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = bandraster.ReadAsArray()
```

So, I'll transform coords using a function:

```
def coord2pixelOffset(rasterfn, x, y):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    originX = geotransform[0]
    originY = geotransform[3]
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
    xOffset = int((x - originX)/pixelWidth)
    yOffset = int((y - originY)/pixelHeight)
    return xOffset, yOffset

CostSurfacefn = 'raster.tif'
source_coord = (-41.1823753163, -13.83393276)
target_coord = (-40.3726182077, -14.2361991946)

# coordinates to array index
source = coord2pixelOffset(CostSurfacefn, source_coord[0], source_coord[1])
target = coord2pixelOffset(CostSurfacefn, target_coord[0], target_coord[1])
```

Next, the graph is loaded and function is called:

```
G = nx.DiGraph(arr)
length, path = nx.bidirectional_dijkstra(G, source, target)
```

But, the function return a error:

> ```
> raise NetworkXError("The node %s is not in the digraph."%(n,))
> ```
>
> networkx.exception.NetworkXError: The node (2612, -352) is not in the digraph.

How to do this in correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy import spatial, stats
import networkx as nx
```

We generate the indice array by computing the euclidean distance betwen each pair of points in the original array of coordinates. I have `a` and `b` for the coordinates, with `a` the x-coordinate and `b` the y-coordinate. I use scipy to construct the indice matrix, then transform it into a graph with networkx

```py
a = np.array([0,0,5,.5,1,1])
b = np.array([0,1,5,.5,0,1])

ab = np.vstack((a,b)).T
m = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(ab, ab)

G = nx.from_numpy_array(m,  create_using=nx.DiGraph)
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]